# how to convert string into complex array of struct and explode in hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, struct, hive, explode

I have below hive table

```
id     string 
code   string
config string
```

values:

```
dummyID|codeA|[{"pmc":"111","scc":"aa1","pgtp":"a22","pgn":"a33","pgrc":"a44"},{"pmc":"222","scc":"bb1","pgtp":"b22","pgn":"b33","pgrc":"b44","sen":"b77"},{"pmc":"333","scc":"cc1","pgtp":"c22","pgn":"c33","pgrc":"c44","pscc":[],"mapb":"c88"},{"pmc":"444","scc":"dd1","pgtp":"d22","pgn":"d33","pgrc":"d44","pscc":["ghgh"],"mapb":"d88"},{"pmc":"555","scc":"ee1","pgtp":"e22","pgn":"e33","pgrc":"e44","mapb":"e88"}]
```

I need to explode the array like below output : ( any of the elements under struct can be optional)

```
dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"111","scc":"aa1","pgtp":"a22","pgn":"a33","pgrc":"a44"}
dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"222","scc":"bb1","pgtp":"b22","pgn":"b33","pgrc":"b44","sen":"b77"}
dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"333","scc":"cc1","pgtp":"c22","pgn":"c33","pgrc":"c44","pscc":[{"qtgm":"tt1","swrt":"rr2"}],"mapb":"c88"}
dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"444","scc":"dd1","pgtp":"d22","pgn":"d33","pgrc":"d44","pscc":["ghgh"],"mapb":"d88"}
dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"555","scc":"ee1","pgtp":"e22","pgn":"e33","pgrc":"e44","mapb":"e88"}
```

I tried:

```
select 
id,
code,
exp_val   
FROM   temp 
LATERAL VIEW explode(array(config)) temp AS exp_val ;
```

above query is not giving any error but not exploding and getting single row,
lateral view inline didn't work too

I tried to create table with below schema and tried to insert records from above string config field but it failed with data type mismatch error

```
id    string,
code  string,
config  array<struct<pmc:String,scc:String,pgtp:string,pgn:string,pgrc:string,pscc:Array<String>,sen:Array<String>,mapb:Array<String>>>
```

when I tried to run select query for config i got below result

```
|dummyID|codeA|{"pmc":"[{\"pmc\":\"111\",\"scc\":\"aa1\",\"pgtp\":\"a22\",\"pgn\":\"a33\",\"pgrc\":\"a44\"},{\"pmc\":\"222\",\"scc\":\"bb1\",\"pgtp\":\"b22\",\"pgn\":\"b33\",\"pgrc\":\"b44\",\"sen\":\"b77\"},{\"pmc\":\"333\",\"scc\":\"cc1\",\"pgtp\":\"c22\",\"pgn\":\"c33\",\"pgrc\":\"c44\",\"pscc\":[],\"mapb\":\"c88\"},{\"pmc\":\"444\",\"scc\":\"dd1\",\"pgtp\":\"d22\",\"pgn\":\"d33\",\"pgrc\":\"d44\",\"pscc\":[\"ghgh\"],\"mapb\":\"d88\"},{\"pmc\":\"555\",\"scc\":\"ee1\",\"pgtp\":\"e22\",\"pgn\":\"e33\",\"pgrc\":\"e44\",\"mapb\":\"e88\"}]","scc":null,"pgtp":null,"pgn":null,"pgrc":null,"pscc":null,"sen":null,"mapb":null}
```

Explode did'nt work on this dataset too

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove `array` inside explode function and try the following

```
select 
 id,
 code,
 exp_val   
FROM temp 
LATERAL VIEW explode(config) temp AS exp_val ;
```

**Second Option:**

```
select 
 t.id,
 t.code,
 e.*   
FROM temp t
LATERAL VIEW outer inline(t.config) e ;
```

Comment: config  is defined as string in 1st case so i applied array however i tried removing that it didn't explode array into multiple rows

Comment: @ashwini added second option, try it out and let me know.

Comment: thanks i tried that too, problem here is that config is defined as string in source and its not able to convert it as array of struct

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach,

First `SPLIT` the String to transform it in Array of Type String.

Second `Explode` the array.

As an example

```sql
WITH table AS(
select 'dummyID' AS id,'codeA' AS code, SPLIT('[{"pmc":"111","scc":"aa1","pgtp":"a22","pgn":"a33","pgrc":"a44"},{"pmc":"222","scc":"bb1","pgtp":"b22","pgn":"b33","pgrc":"b44","sen":"b77"},{"pmc":"333","scc":"cc1","pgtp":"c22","pgn":"c33","pgrc":"c44","pscc":[],"mapb":"c88"},{"pmc":"444","scc":"dd1","pgtp":"d22","pgn":"d33","pgrc":"d44","pscc":["ghgh"],"mapb":"d88"},{"pmc":"555","scc":"ee1","pgtp":"e22","pgn":"e33","pgrc":"e44","mapb":"e88"}]','\\{') AS array)
SELECT id,code, exp_val
FROM   table
LATERAL VIEW explode(array) table AS exp_val;
```

ouput

```sql
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|    id    |  code  |                      exp_val                       |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| dummyID  | codeA  | [                                                  |
| dummyID  | codeA  | "pmc":"111","scc":"aa1","pgtp":"a22","pgn":"a33","pgrc":"a44"}, |
| dummyID  | codeA  | "pmc":"222","scc":"bb1","pgtp":"b22","pgn":"b33","pgrc":"b44","sen":"b77"}, |
| dummyID  | codeA  | "pmc":"333","scc":"cc1","pgtp":"c22","pgn":"c33","pgrc":"c44","pscc":[],"mapb":"c88"}, |
| dummyID  | codeA  | "pmc":"444","scc":"dd1","pgtp":"d22","pgn":"d33","pgrc":"d44","pscc":["ghgh"],"mapb":"d88"}, |
| dummyID  | codeA  | "pmc":"555","scc":"ee1","pgtp":"e22","pgn":"e33","pgrc":"e44","mapb":"e88"}] |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: thanks I want entire struct as a row so tried split with } but any of the field inside strcut can contain other nested struct that will lead scenarios which split can't work with bcz it can have another row with {} inside outer {}

Comment: I changed the query with other pattern, you can use substr, replace, and concat for tunning exp_val in a stage table.

Comment: thanks.. i tried its working except for scenarios where I hv nested struct inside pscc .. updated source data..!!